# Keeping error information and the outer observable alive

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, rxjs-observables

To ensure an error doesn't complete the **outer** observable, a common [rxjs effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) pattern I've adopted is:

```js
 public saySomething$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {

    return this.actions.pipe(

      ofType<AppActions.SaySomething>(AppActions.SAY_SOMETHING),

      // Switch to the result of the inner observable.
      switchMap((action) => {
        // This service could fail.
        return this.service.saySomething(action.payload).pipe(
          // Return `null` to keep the outer observable alive!
          catchError((error) => {
            // What can I do with error here?
            return of(null);
          })
        )
      }),

      // The result could be null because something could go wrong.
      tap((result: Result | null) => {
        if (result) {
          // Do something with the result!
        }
      }),

      // Update the store state.
      map((result: Result | null) => {
        if (result) {
          return new AppActions.SaySomethingSuccess(result);
        }
        // It would be nice if I had access the **error** here. 
        return new AppActions.SaySomethingFail();
      }));
});
```

Notice that I'm using `catchError` on the **inner** observable to keep the **outer** observable alive if the underlying network call fails (`service.saySomething(action.payload)`):

```js
catchError((error) => {
  // What can I do with error here?
  return of(null);
})
```

The subsequent `tap` and `map` operators accommodate this in their signatures by allowing `null`, i.e. `(result: Result | null)`. However, I lose the error information. Ultimately when the final `map` method returns `new AppActions.SaySomethingFail();` I have lost any information about the error.

How can I keep the error information throughout the pipe rather than losing it at the point it's caught?

Comment: Can't you just `return of(error);`?

Comment: @józef-podlecki I could, but then how would I distinguish in `tap` and `map` between an error and a successful result?

Comment: [...with a type guard?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Comment: That seems to cause an error `tap((result: Result | null) => result is Result {` is warning that `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments you should use [Type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Unfortunately I can't run typescript in snippet so I commented types

```js
const { of, throwError, operators: {
    switchMap,
    tap,
    map,
    catchError
  }
} = rxjs;

const actions = of({payload: 'data'});

const service = {
  saySomething: () => throwError(new Error('test'))
}

const AppActions = {
}

AppActions.SaySomethingSuccess = function () {
}
AppActions.SaySomethingFail = function() {
}

/* Type guard */
function isError(value/*: Result | Error*/)/* value is Error*/ {
  return value instanceof Error;
}

const observable = actions.pipe(
  switchMap((action) => {
    
    return service.saySomething(action.payload).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        return of(error);
      })
    )
  }),
  tap((result/*: Result | Error*/) => {
    if (isError(result)) {
      console.log('tap error')
      return;
    }
    
    console.log('tap result');
  }),
  map((result/*: Result | Error*/) => {
    if (isError(result)) {
      console.log('map error')
      return new AppActions.SaySomethingFail();
    }
    
    console.log('map result');
    return new AppActions.SaySomethingSuccess(result);
  }));
  
  observable.subscribe(_ => {

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it'll do the job, but it doesn't seem very functional or ngrx-like. I'm surprised it comes down to inspecting the type of a variable considering I know at the point the error is caught, that I have an error and not a valid result. Another issue is that errors often have `any` type, which means I need to construct a new `Error` object so instance works reliably. This is starting to feel hacky.

Comment: I noticed that since the parameter to `tap` and `map` can now be either a `Result` or `Error` that the compiler complains that the value may not have certain (`Result`) properties, even after checking if it's an instance of `Error`.

Comment: how is `Result` defined?

Comment: It's an interface; `interface Result { ... }`. My type guard wasn't returning a type predicate, so the compiler complained. After ensuring the return type is `value is Error` the compiler was happy.

Comment: [I tried on playground and intellisense didnt show any red flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4FcA2ZkDeAUMsgA5QD2ZAjAFzIZhSgDmA3CeVWQEwMgsAWwBG0TqQrUAzA0oiAVhARhOAXyJEYWECuCUQyYBgCiUKlAAUANzg4sEBumx5kAH2RmLASga37KMae5pRQhFxQEGBYUIb+DkYgTHC6EJQwwRbqmtq6YPqGYHBkNnYOTpi4+B5eod7hpMAZlsa1VvEQ3vXEpKQIBhiUOBAAdDiUrKUBIyBwQp0Svf1JQ6Pjkx0j8xgYcKwLXKSR0bFcGlzLg8NjE1MOI1K03ouXqzcbZaOPvM8XA2-rO5fHjSX5qIA)

Comment: Ah ok nvm. Didnt see the full response

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to keep the error information throughout the pipe. Instead you should separate your success pipeline (`tap`, `map`) from your error pipeline (`catchError`) by adding all operators to the observable whose result they should actually work with, i.e. your inner observable.

```ts
public saySomething$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {

    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType<AppActions.SaySomething>(AppActions.SAY_SOMETHING),
      switchMap((action) => this.service.saySomething(action.payload).pipe(
        tap((result: Result) => {
          // Do something with the result!
        }),
        // Update the store state.
        map((result: Result) => {
          return new AppActions.SaySomethingSuccess(result);
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          // I can access the **error** here. 
          return of(new AppActions.SaySomethingFail());
        })
      )),     
    );
});
```

This way `tap` and `map` will only be executed on success results from `this.service.saySomething`. Move all your error side effects and error mapping into `catchError`.